# Error : ERROR: (gcloud.logging.sinks.create) User [nataraj@somedomaindonamehere] does not have permission to access organization

Tags: google-cloud-storage, stackdriver

I am trying to create a sink to monitor VPC_FLOW LOGS for all the projects in an organization and i am getting permission denied, has anybody else have a similar issue ?. Error is clear that it's permissiond denied but what permission do i need to create this ?

Environment: I am logging with somebody@domainname.com (gsuite user)

From Command Line:

```
gcloud beta logging sinks create somesinknamehere --include-children --log-filter='resource.type="gce_subnetwork"' storage.googleapis.com/somebuckethere   --organization=organizations/0000000000
```

Error : ERROR: (gcloud.logging.sinks.create) User [nataraj@somedomaindonamehere] does not have permission to access organization [0000000000] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission.

API

```
Request

POST https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/organizations/00000000000/sinks?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "destination": "storage.googleapis.com/somebucket",
 "filter": "resource.type=\"gce_subnetwork",
 "name": "somenamehere",
 "includeChildren": true
}

Response

403

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The caller does not have permission",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
 }
}
```

I tried the beta API and below is  the response

```
Request

POST https://logging.googleapis.com/v2beta1/organizations/0000000000/sinks?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
“destination”: “storage.googleapis.com/somebucketnamehere”,
“filter”: “resource.type=\“gce_subnetwork”,
“name”: “somesinknamehere”,
“includeChildren”: true
}
```

Response

404

```html
Show headers -
<title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title> <style> *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px} </style>
404. That’s an error.
```

The requested URL /v2beta1/organizations/0000000000/sinks?key=somekeynamehjere&alt=json was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue after having the right permissions to the user. I enabled the user with 1) Organization Administrator, 2) Billing Administrator and Logging Admin roles.

Comment: For the benefit of the community would you provide the solution in an answer rather than a comment ?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue after having the right permissions to the user. 


I enabled the user with 

 1) Organization Administrator, 
 2) Billing Administrator and 
 3) Logging Admin roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarifying @Nataraj comments as an answer, as per this [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/aggregated_exports?hl=th#creating_an_aggregated_export_sinkaggregated-sinks),

> you must have the Logs Configuration Writer IAM role for the parent to
>   create the sink.

Thus, giving

> 1) Organization Administrator, 2) Billing Administrator and 3)
>   Logging Admin roles

However, such permissions can be more granular per the parent (Organization), and this [access control guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control?hl=th) should help. On another note, it is a best practice to grant roles and configure ownership/access to [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts?hl=th#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource) rather than users.